# Set buttons same size indepentent of text size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So i had a solution to do something like this:

[image: image1]

the problem was that everytime i had a little bigger text my button increased, and it became really ugly since i have a section full of buttons that i want to preserve the same size.

So i think a good option would be to mantain the same size for the buttons? (if there is other option would like to know :)).

So i had this:

```
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <button class="btn btn-primary-outline btn-small">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>
                    <br><span class="fontSize">Image</span>
                </button>
            </div>
```

how can i change my solution to have the same effect i want on the button, i mean with the image and text centered related to the image mantaining the size of the button? any help i appreciate :)

Thanks

Comment: Add CSS to fix the min-height and min-width of the button, and use flexbox or absolute positioning to center the elements inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? (I know, it's ugly)

```css
#test{
  min-width: 5px;
  max-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button id="test">test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/r3g31e11/1/

```css
.btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="btn btn-primary">
Submit
</button>
<br/>
<br/>

<button class="btn btn-primary">
Testisnottoincreasebuttonwidth
</button>
```

Truncate the extra character use **ellipse**. Set height & width of the button.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.test {
width : 80px;
}

.test > span {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    width:40px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-1">
  <button class="btn btn-primary-outline btn-small test"><span>Test</span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary-outline btn-small test"><span>Test with large size</span></button>
</div>
```